# Why am I OVER_QUERY_LIMIT when using Google's Geocoder API?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have this application that lets me put in an address and get the lat/lng via Google's Geocoding API. I use AJAX to call a PHP script which creates the Google Geocoder API call, it looks like this:

```
    $base_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=";
    $address = urlencode($addy1 . ' ' . $addy2);
    $url = $base_url.$address;
```

where $addy1 is the street address and $addy2 is the City/State/Zip in the proper format for geocoding.

When I perform a file_get_contents on that $url, I consistently get a 'status'=>OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

I do not come even close to reaching the 2500 query limit per day. I have tried maybe 15 different addresses so far today, and I didn't work at all yesterday.

As an aside, we have been having this issue since Monday morning. We did recently move the application to a cloud solution. Is it possible that we are receiving an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT due to the nature of shared IP's on the cloud?

I don't have any other solutions for this. Using an API Key ends with a REQUEST_DENIED response, since the Geocoding API doesn't use an API Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been having this issue since Monday morning. We did recently move the application to a cloud solution. Is it possible that we are receiving an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT due to the nature of shared IP's on the cloud?

This is the most likely answer.  Can you move the geocoding to the client side?

EDIT: another option would be to see if you can get a dedicated IP address for your server that does the geocoding.

[Similar query from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766222/google-maps-v3-api-over-query-limit-but-just-1-request)

Comment: I may have to move it client-side at this point, since Rackspace is telling me there isn't much they can do about it. Is this the only viable alternative? (It seems other geocoding services have similar limits in place.)

Comment: I will probably approach my boss with a solution that requires us to host web services, as we already have a dedicated server. It's just not the solution I had hoped for, which was to keep everything in one domain and hidden from the average user.

Comment: Oh, you're using Rackspace. Virtual IP addresses are an enormous problem: you are sharing your connection to the internet with lots of other users and sharing quotas/rate limits. Client-side is always better; there are very few occasions when server-side is entirely appropriate.

Comment: My only real issue with doing this on the client-side is that I have to do a lot of added processing, validating against the current db state, making sure i have uniqueness across the various tables involved, as well as actual processing of the data. It's simply easier to contain the bulk of the handling/retrieving in one spot. It is also less-prone to errors.